# onClick -> Fiddle works on the first click, but stops working - mistery

Tags: javascript, onclick, layer, mask

I have this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sebababi/dFp6f/) which works once.

```
function toggle_off(itemID){
  alert(itemID+'->'+document.getElementById(itemID).getAttribute("style"));
  document.getElementById(itemID).style.display = 'none';
}

function maskIt(x){
  alert(x);
  var mask = document.createElement('div');
  mask.id = 'maskIt';
  mask.setAttribute("class", "maskIt");
  mask.onclick = function(){toggle_off('maskIt');}
  mask.innerHTML = 'click to close mask';
  document.body.appendChild(mask);
}
```

On click it opens a mask (layer), on mask click - closes it self - all fine up to here.

On second click, the mask opens again, but when you click on it the second time it won't close.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of hiding the div you should remove it as you are creating a new div each click

```
function toggle_off(itemID){
  alert(itemID+'->'+document.getElementById(itemID).getAttribute("style"));
  var mask = document.getElementById(itemID);
  mask.parentNode.removeChild(mask);
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/dFp6f/1/)

Answer (score 1):

You are not destroying the first instance of "maskIt" when you close the overlay, so they build up in the background. If you inspect the page after the second click, you will see two maskIt divs, the first one hidden.

When you call getElementById('maskIt'), it will find the first, hidden, one in the document, and so not hide the second.

Why not reuse the first mask?

```
function toggle_off(itemID) {
  alert(itemID + '->' + document.getElementById(itemID).getAttribute("style"));
  document.getElementById(itemID).style.display = 'none';
}

function maskIt(x) {
  alert(x);
  var mask = document.getElementById('maskIt');
  if (mask == null) {
    mask = document.createElement('div');
    mask.id = 'maskIt';
    mask.setAttribute("class", "maskIt");
    mask.onclick = function () {
      toggle_off('maskIt');
    }
    mask.innerHTML = 'click to close mask';
    document.body.appendChild(mask);
  }
  else
  {
    mask.style.display = "block";
  }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dFp6f/2/